# Kotlin and WebSockets

Tags: websocket, kotlin

I'm making a small server-side application that will communicate with a browser via WebSockets, and am considering writing it in Kotlin.

Is there a WebSockets API that works particularly well with Kotlin, or will any Java WebSockets API fit the bill?

Comment: In case you're not aware of them:

There's already a Web Framework being developed called Kara:
http://karaframework.com/

Also, there's Node.kt that's obviously inspired by Node.js:
http://jonninja.github.io/node.kt/

I'm not certain whether they currently have Web Sockets support but even if they don't they can constitute a base for your work or even better you could even contribute.

Comment: Just now I am going to publish WebSockets example based on RxKotlin and OkHttp. Will do it in a few days after M11 release

Answer (score 4):

This [library](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) worked for me very well in Kotlin. Actually, most java libraries worked well for me with Kotlin.

**Update**
There was recently released a [module](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-ws) for [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library that supports WebSockets. It's a beta version but I would give it a try since OkHttp itself works well with Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

Its a couple of year's leater, but I would consider checking out [javalin](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin) and [ktor.io](http://ktor.io)

Comment: This are two web frameworks, but I cannot see what this has to do with WebSockets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Java lib: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

We're currently using it for a websocket projet as well, and it's working fine with the v13 (unlike python lib).

Comment: Are you using it with Kotlin? Can you comment on that specifically from experience?

Comment: No we're not using Kotlin, just javascript client side and Java server side. But I don't think it's a problem, I guess you could use the lib by calling external symbols from your Kotlin code, I'm not an expert in Java but I'm think of dll/.so for C++ or even C-written module for python. But anyway if it is too much work to use a lib you can style write it from scratch, the protocol isn't that complicated and you can find a bunch of exemples on the net.

Comment: I use Jetty with Kotlin (not for websockets, just servlets) and it works fine. In general, Kotlin will work well with any Java library. Just make sure to do your null checking when appropriate.