# Websocket connection in kotlin?

Tags: xml, gradle, kotlin

I developed android application in java but now I shifted to Kotlin so I don't know how to connect websocket in kotlin please help out

Comment: Please read [How to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [John's post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin and WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302453/kotlin-and-websockets)